# Userevent button to trigger clientscript and open suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a button created with a userevent script which appears on a transaction record
[image: userevent button]
This is supposed to trigger a client script on click which in turn is supposed to redirect to a suitelet.

So far, I am not getting an error message though it is not doing anything either.
I am following SuiteAnswers id: 93513 for the basic structure as I am trying to pass the parameters of the record the user is on, to the suitelet.
i.e. if the user clicks on the 'add note' button while on invoice(internal id-38060), I want that value to be set in the Suitelet form under the field 'Parent transaction'.
Where am I going wrong with my script?
edit: there are two different variations of this that now work. The first is using only a userevent script and suitelet (getting rid of the client script) and the other is the tweaked client script to include the n/currentRecord module
Userevent Script:

```js
   /**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(["N/url", "N/record", "N/runtime", "N/ui/serverWidget"], function (
    url,
    record,
    runtime,
    serverWidget
) {
    var exports = {}

    /**
     * @param {UserEventContext.beforeLoad} context
     */
    function beforeLoad(context) {
        if (
            context.type == context.UserEventType.EDIT ||
            context.type == context.UserEventType.VIEW
        ) {
            var record = context.newRecord
            var recordId = record.id
            var recordType = record.type

            var form = context.form
            //the internal id of the client script file in the filing cabinet
             form.clientScriptFileId = 4910

            var suiteletURL = url.resolveScript({
                scriptId: "customscript_suitelet_notes",
                deploymentId: "customdeploy_suitelet_notes",
                returnExternalUrl: true,
                params: { recordId: recordId, recordType: recordType },
            })

            form.addButton({
                id: "custpage_add_note",
                label: "Add Note",
                functionName:"onclick_callforSuitelet"
              
              
              
//                  "window.open('" +
//                  suiteletURL +
                    //"','PopUpWindow','height=500,width=1000,left=120,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,//toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');",
            })
        }
    }

    
    return {beforeLoad:beforeLoad}
})
```

Client script:

```js
   /**
     *@NApiVersion 2.x
     *@NScriptType ClientScript
     */
    define(["N/record", "N/url",'N/currentRecord'], function (record, url,currentRecord) {
      /**
       * @param {ClientScriptContext.pageInit} context
       * @param {ClientScriptContext.onclick_callforSuitelet} context
       */
     function pageInit() {}
      function onclick_callforSuitelet() {
        var record = currentRecord.get();
        var recordId = record.id;
        var recordType = record.type;
        log.debug("recId", recordId);
        log.debug("recType", recordType);
    
        //this is the script id on the script record for the suitelet (not the deployment)
        var suiteletURL = url.resolveScript({
          scriptId: "customscript_suitelet_notes",
          //this is the id from the deployment record for the suitelet
          deploymentId: "customdeploy_suitelet_notes",
          params: { recordId: recordId, recordType: recordType },
        });
        document.location = suiteletURL;
        log.debug("suiteletURL", suiteletURL);
      }
    
      return {
        onclick_callforSuitelet: onclick_callforSuitelet,
      pageInit: pageInit,
      };
    });
```

Suitelet script

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(["N/ui/serverWidget", "N/log", "N/record", "N/url"], function (
    serverWidget,
    log,
    record,
    url
) {
    /**
     * @param {SuiteletContext.onRequest} context
     */
    function onRequest(context) {
        if (context.request.method === "GET") {
            // Section One - Forms
            var invoice_id = parseInt(context.request.parameters.recordId)

            var form = serverWidget.createForm({
                id: "notes",
                title: "Notes",
            })

            var customerGroup = form.addFieldGroup({
                id: "customerDetails",
                label: "Customer Details",
            })
            customerGroup.isSingleColumn = false

            form.addSubmitButton({
                label: "Submit",
            })

            var select = form.addField({
                id: "custpage_source",
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
                label: "Source of Communication",
                container: "customerDetails",
            })
            //the value is the internal id of the option under customisation>lists,records and forms>lists>'source of communication' list
            select.addSelectOption({
                value: 1,
                text: "Phone",
            })

            select.addSelectOption({
                value: 2,
                text: "Email",
            })

            select.addSelectOption({
                value: 3,
                text: "Website Contact Form",
            })

            select.addSelectOption({
                value: 4,
                text: "Other",
            })

            form.addPageLink({
                type: serverWidget.FormPageLinkType.CROSSLINK,
                title: "Invoice",
                url:
                    "https://tstdrv2559160.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/custinvc.nl?id=" +
                    invoice_id,
            })

            var parentTransaction = form.addField({
                id: "custpage_parent_transaction",
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
                label: "Parent Transaction",
                container: "customerDetails",
            })

            parentTransaction.addSelectOption({ value: invoice_id, text: invoice_id })

            // form.updateDefaultValues({
            //   custpage_recordurl:
            //     "https://tstdrv2559160.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/custinvc.nl?id=" +
            //     recId,
            // });
            context.response.writePage(form)

            function getBaseUrl() {
                return url.resolveRecord({
                    recordType: record.Type.INVOICE,
                })
            }
            // Section Two - Tabs - See "Steps for Adding a Tab to a Form"
            // Section Three - Sublist - See "Steps for Adding a Sublist to a Form"
        } else {
            // Section Four - Output - Used in all sections

            var delimiter = /\u0001/
            var sourceField = context.request.parameters.custpage_source
            var parentField = context.request.parameters.custpage_parent_transaction

            var invoiceRecord = record.load({
                type: record.Type.INVOICE,
                id: parentField,
            })
            log.debug("parent record", invoiceRecord)

            //   context.response.write(
            //     "You have entered:" + "<br/>  Name: " + sourceField
            //   );
            var recObj = record.create({
                type: "customrecord_user_notes",
            })
            recObj.setValue({ fieldId: "custrecord_source", value: sourceField })
            recObj.setValue({
                fieldId: "custrecord_parent_transaction",
                value: parentField,
            })
            var userNote = recObj.save({})
            var notesFieldUpdate = record.submitFields({
                type: record.Type.INVOICE,
                id: parentField,
                values: { custbody_notes_check: "CHECK NOTES" },
            })
            log.debug("notesfield", notesFieldUpdate)

            context.response.write("Note Created")
        }
    }
    return {
        onRequest: onRequest,
    }
})
```

At the moment, I haven't completed the suitelet form though it is working correctly in that it is creating a instance of a custom record using the field data entered by the user:
[image: suitelet]

I hadn't defined the record context which is why it was doing nothing. I could only see it after looking at the console log and seeing an error message in that

Thanks Sitaram and ZSwitaj for their suggestions

Comment: @sitaram Thanks for the suggestion. It still does nothing though and doesn't open the suitelet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form.addButton({
            id: "custpage_add_note",
            label: "Add Note",
            functionName: "onclick_callforSuitelet()",
          });
```

Use `onclick_callforSuitelet` instead of `onclick_callforSuitelet()` in the function name.

Comment: In the client script use the var rec = current record.get() by loading in 'N/currentRecord' and use rec.id to get the Id. Let me know if this works

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't have access to the `context` within your client script in a user-defined function like yours. `log.debug()` also tends to not work well with client scripts, using `console.log()` and opening the browser console tends to lead to better debugging.

If you change your `log.debug()` functions to `console.log()` and run the script (aka press your button), do `recordId` and `recordType` logs give you expected results?

According to [SuiteAnswer 93513](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/93513/kw/93513) you should be able to use `currentRecord.get()` to get your current record. May not solve all your problems, but hopefully can get you rolling again!